# Remove a column which was added recently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

There was a time when I had to a column "`column`" to a model. Now I have to remove it. Is there any sensible method to that except a simple one by adding a new migration?

Comment: Adding migration file is best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how deep down the rabbit hole you are you can rollback then delete the migration.

```
rake db:rollback

rails destroy migration *name of migration*
```

This will run the down method of the migration undoing the column add. The second command destroys the migration resetting your schema file.

EDIT:

Turns out your rabbit hole is deep. Best thing to do is to make another migration removing the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course run SQL directly on the database. The problem with not using a migration file to perform this "subtle change" is that if you ever have to move your application to another server, you won't be able to recreate the database: this "column" column will be there because it's removal was never documented.

Stick with migrations!